# Cannot register a client - Spring Boot Admin 2.0.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-admin

I am developing according with documentation: https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.2, but i don't getting register a client in a secure application.

My configuration are:

application.yml

```
# Security config
spring.security.user:
  name: admin
  password: admin

# Actuator config
management:
  endpoint:
    shutdown.enabled: true
    health.show-details: always
  endpoints.web.exposure.include: '*'

# Spring boot admin config
spring.boot.admin:
  context-path: /admin
  client:
    url: http://localhost:8080/admin
    username: ${spring.security.user.name}
    password: ${spring.security.user.password}
    instance:
      name: ${app.name}
      metadata.user:
        name: ${spring.security.user.name}
        password: ${spring.security.user.password}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final String adminContextPath;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties) {
        this.adminContextPath = adminServerProperties.getContextPath();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");
        successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(adminContextPath + "/");

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage(adminContextPath + "/login").successHandler(successHandler).and()
                .logout().logoutUrl(adminContextPath + "/logout").and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/instances", "/actuator/**");
    }

}
```

And the error is occurring:

`2018-08-22 00:44:21.770 DEBUG 9616 --- [gistrationTask1] d.c.b.a.c.r.ApplicationRegistrator: Failed to register application as Application(name=template-api, managementUrl=http://localhost:8080/actuator, healthUrl=http://localhost:8080/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://localhost:8080/) at spring-boot-admin ([http://localhost:8080/admin/instances]): 401 null`

Can someone please help with this `401`?

**UPDATED 2018-09-01:**

I tried separate configs and the same error occurs:

Server:

```
# Security config
spring.security.user:
  name: test-name
  password: test-password

# Spring boot admin config  
spring.boot.admin:
  context-path: /admin
```

Client:

```
# Spring boot admin config
spring.boot.admin:
  client:
    url: http://localhost:8080/admin
    username: test-name
    password: test-password
    instance:
      name: ${app.name}
      metadata.user:
        name: test-name
        password: test-password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the Spring Boot Admin documentation. It was fixed.

https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/894

Answer (score 0):

401 Unauthorized error is an HTTP status code that means the page you were trying to access cannot be loaded until you first log in with a valid user ID and password. Have you configured your client and admin server correctly??

You can take a look at my sample source code for server and client spring boot applications with and without security configurations here.
https://github.com/anandvarkeyphilips/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-samples

Comment: I did the configurations according to the spring boot admin documentation. I think it's right. I have already tried setting up separate client and server, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Okay..Please post client and admin configuration separately. We'll try.

Comment: I edited the original post with the separate configs.

Comment: I have added working examples for sba examples with and without security. Please take a look at it and let me know. I have also raised a ticket for this. https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/910